# Mercurial patch import via pipe

Tags: shell, mercurial

I would like to avoid avoid a file on disk when applying a patch with mercurial

Instead of `./script_gen_diff > diff && hg import diff && rm diff`, I would like to be able to `./script_gen_diff | hg import`. Is it possible ? There's no such option in the doc.

Comment: Honestly, trying what you asked would have been quicker than writing the question here. Additionally: in both your examples you have a file, just differently named.

Comment: yeah, that's a bad example. The real example is `arc export --revision D54 | hg import`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There's no such option in the doc

RLLY?! I can read `hg help import` and discover

> hg import [OPTION]... PATCH ...
>
> ...
>
> ```
> To read a patch from standard input, use "-" as the patch name. If a URL
> is specified, the patch will be downloaded from there.
> ```

Comment: Thanks, you got me, I skimmed through the doc too fast